# Vienna Contract on Road Traffic - can I take my E-Bike (Moped) abroad?

Tags: international, traffic, motor-vehicle

I did some research on that topic, but it did not really become clear to me.

Situation: I live in Switzerland. Switzerland did not declare to treat Mopeds as Motor Cycles - Article 54 (2). My fast electric bike is registered here as Moped, it complies with the swiss regulations, the rules of article 44(2) and has a swiss number plate and documents. It has a power of 1000W. However, in many other countries fast electric bikes must not have more than 500W to be registered as mopeds.

Questions:

1) Can I drive it in a country which did not declare to treat Mopeds as Motor Cycles (e.g. Austria)? In other words: is compliance to the rules of the vienna contract and the swiss decision, that my E-Bike with 1000W is a Moped allow its use in those countries?

2) Can I drive it in a country which declared to treat Mopeds as Motor Cycles (e.g. Germany), if it complies to the rules of the contract, especially the technical rules of appendix 5?

Comment: 1.000 watts is effectively nothing, the bike wouldn't be able to move itself, let alone help with the rider. It's also certainly less than 500 watts.

Comment: @Nij many countries use the period for the thousands separator.  In those countries, 1.000 watts is twice as much as 500 watts.  Switzerland is one of those countries.  Now that I've edited the question, is it clearer?

Comment: Hahaha, sorry, those misunderstandings are so funny. Yes, at least in central european countries, the point seperates thousands and comma the decimals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system - actually switzerland is kind of mixed...